# We used to not be able to access all properties at once from a union in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

As title. I bought an online course I had no time to watch until now. In the course, it says something like this *was* not allowed in TypeScript:

```
type Name = { name: string }
type Age = { age: number }

type UnionBoth = Name | Age

const test = (union: UnionBoth): void => {
    if ('name' in union && 'age' in union) {
        union.name
        union.age
    }
}
```

But after testing on the current version `5.4.3`, it works without an error. I started testing the same code on the previous version and repeated it. Finally, I hit [an error on the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/FAguE8AcFMAIDkCGBbOBeWBvWA7F0AuWAZ1ACcBLHAc1gF9gIZYBBa9LWRdonAV2QAjaGXpgocAKo4KAexwAhWaAAWsDElSwAPq3YgAxvNKxQ0ExgAUfGfKLS5i5SoCURAG6yKAE3UA+LGBYYNgKADNYSwByPFQo0JxYG0dYADJU2CjuaHiqJNscF0CQkvzHADpY6CDS4OT5cuya4IY6IA) at `4.8.4`:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'age' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Any explanation? The course tried to "change" my mental model by saying that union might not be *the intuitive way* we think. Now this is not an error so what's the correct mental model for understanding the code above, correctly?

---

Just checked that the code at `5.4.3` the inference type of `union` in the function is of the type:

```
(parameter) union: Name & Record<"age", unknown>
```

Why is there a `Record` here just for the property `age`?

---

My current mental model:

1. There are two sets `Name` and `Age`.
2. The union `union` of the function can fall into one of the three cases:

   1. it is in `Name` only.
   2. it is in `Age` only.
   3. it is in the intersection, i.e. `Name & Age`.
3. By the type-narrowing of the `if` statement, TypeScript should understand that the case is 3 and we should be able to access both `name` and `age` inside the block.

Comment: `Why is there a Record here just for the property age?` — it infers the type as `Name` because check for `name` is the first in `if`, and adds `age` because it's possible to get in the body of `if` only if there are both of those fields. Previously, there were **no** possible types that had both of those fields, therefore `never` type(type that has no value, unconstructable) was inferred.

Comment: "it is in the intersection, i.e. Name & Age." — `union` type is either: either `Name` or `Age`. In 4.8.4 it was strict, now it's either `Name + additional fields` or `Age + additional fields`. But only one type is inferred. Type inferrer in your example can't even guess what type of `age` property is, because it infers just `Name + some extra unknown "age"`.

Comment: @user28434'mstep So it sounds like my metal model for TypeScript is incorrect: TypeScript somehow short-circuitly concluded the type with only the first part of the condition? So no sets here?

Comment: Yep, it looks like it. If you will change condition in `test` to `('age' in union && 'name' in union)` you will get a `union: Age & Record<"name", unknown>`

Comment: OK, I probably got what TypeScript was doing after your hints. It is doing something incrementally by gradually shrinking the set from `Name | Age` to `Name` and finally `Name & Age`? But its first step `Name | Age` to `Name` result in the fact that it's adding back the property `age` by using a `Record`?

Comment: Nah, you won't get `Name & Age`, first condition narrows it to one of types, either `Name` or `Age`. But now it assumes that no-declared fields of `unknown` type are there. `age: unknown` is not the same as`age: number` of the `Age` type. Also, check `jcalz` answer below, it's good and explains it better than I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript has always had [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) so that `if ("name" in val)` would serve to narrow `{name: string} | {age: number}` to `{name: string}`.  TypeScript 4.9 introduced [*unlisted property* narrowing with the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#unlisted-property-narrowing-with-the-in-operator), so that `if ("age" in val)` would narrow `{name: string}` to the equivalent of `{name: string; age: unknown}`.  Yes, these features are mutually inconsistent.  You can read the implementing pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#50666](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50666), and the feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) discussing how people want the `in` operator to work, and the tradeoffs involved.

There is no "correct" mental model that works in all circumstances. TypeScript tries to support idiomatic JavaScript, even though this does not actually cohere into a single whole. TypeScript's type system is intentionally [not sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), in order to enable developers to be productive.  Soundness is preferred over unsoundness all else being equal, but developer productivity sometimes matters more. (See [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals).)

TypeScript *usually* treats object types as being open/extendible and not closed/sealed/exact. So the value `{a: "x", b: "y"}` is assignable to `{a: string}` despite its excess `b` property. But such things are also causes of errors, so TypeScript has [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks), and `in` operator narrowing.

---

For the purpose of the `in` operator, I'd say the mental model is the following cognitive dissonance: if you are using `in` to check for a property that exists in some [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members, TypeScript will treat those union types as closed/sealed/exact and eliminate the other members (even though this is technically unsound). If, on the other hand, you are using `in` to check for a property that does not exist in any union member, then it treats the type as open/extendible and just adds a property of `unknown` type to that object type.

Thus, when you write

```
const test = (union: UnionBoth): void => {
    if ('name' in union && 'age' in union) {
        union.name
        union.age
    }
}
```

what happens is: first you check `'name' in union` which narrows `union` from `UnionBoth` to `{name: string}`, *eliminating* `{age: number}`.  Then you check `'age' in union` which narrows `union` from `{name: string}` to `{name: string, age: unknown}`.  This is completely in line with the above mental model, leading to the frankly bizarre situation here. If you switch the order of your `in` tests, you'll get the opposite bizarre thing.

In my opinion, what this shows is: pretty much nobody uses union types the way you're doing now. If they're checking properties with `in`, it's because they are trying to *discriminate* a union, even though it's unsound to do so.  If you really want to do this sort of check, you'll need to refactor your union type to be explicit about how things work:

```
type UnionBoth = Name | Age | (Name & Age)

const test = (union: UnionBoth): void => {
    if ('name' in union && 'age' in union) {
        union;
        // ^? Name & Age
        union.name
        //    ^? string
        union.age
        //    ^? number
    }
}
```

Now the possibility of `Name & Age` is explicitly mentioned, and TypeScript uses its original `in` narrowing to narrow to `Name & Age`, never using the new "unlisted property narrowing" because there's always a union member containing the key you're testing for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigbygO0RAXFAZ2ACcBLTAcygF8AoUSKAQQpXSjlf0wFcEAjCMRq164aAFVMpAPaYAQjOAALKKnhIoAH2attUABQboAMl0QAlKIDGcolGAR7qAz2lz8U2QqXKL+ADcZUgATNQA+dFooGKhSADNDAHJsJCS4zCg3bygTMyTOCHTyLPdMCyjYqtLvAG5o6piAeiaoAD0AfgbG7LkAOlSIbuqWqs7hqt7MPsKJ2NHY8aq6OiA)